Frequent freezes and initramfs error on Ubuntu 24.10
I've been experiencing some frustrating issues with my Ubuntu and Fedora installations. My OS frequently freezes, and when I restart my device, I sometimes encounter an initramfs error. After restarting again, the error goes away, but it's happening more often than I'd like. The freezing issue also occurs on Fedora, but without the initramfs problem. It's quite annoying as it disrupts my workflow.
I've done some searches about this problem and reviewed my logs (attached below). From what I can tell the OS seems fine, so I suspect it might be related to my hardware, however I'm unsure how to 100% confirm that the issue isn't with the kernel or something related to software, but rather with the hardware.
My hardware:
   Laptop: Intel i5-8365U
   RAM: 16GB
   Storage: 256GB SSD M.2
   Power: I use the cable directly
   OS: Ubuntu 24.10
Logs:
https://pastebin.com/RiehURQP
Nov 03 01:12:23 khxpc google-chrome.desktop[2907]: [3186:16:1103/011223.251433:ERROR:shared_image_interface_proxy.cc(134)] Buffer handle is null. Not creating a mailbox from it.
Nov 03 01:13:43 khxpc google-chrome.desktop[2907]: [2900:2931:1103/011343.974554:ERROR:registration_request.cc(291)] Registration response error message: DEPRECATED_ENDPOINT
Nov 03 01:15:01 khxpc CRON[4734]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Nov 03 01:15:01 khxpc CRON[4735]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Nov 03 01:15:01 khxpc CRON[4734]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 03 01:16:10 khxpc gnome-shell[2079]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 79 with keysym 79 (keycode 1d).
Nov 03 01:16:10 khxpc gnome-shell[2079]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keysym 73 (keycode 27).
Nov 03 01:16:10 khxpc gnome-shell[2079]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 6c with keysym 2f (keycode 2e).
Nov 03 01:17:01 khxpc CRON[5019]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Nov 03 01:17:01 khxpc CRON[5020]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov 03 01:17:01 khxpc CRON[5019]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 03 01:20:16 khxpc systemd[1]: Starting sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool...
Nov 03 01:20:16 khxpc systemd[1]: sysstat-collect.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 03 01:20:16 khxpc systemd[1]: Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.
Nov 03 01:20:27 khxpc systemd[1]: Starting systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service - Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Nov 03 01:20:27 khxpc systemd-tmpfiles[5404]: /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/legacy.conf:13: Duplicate line for path "/run/lock", ignoring.
Nov 03 01:20:27 khxpc systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 03 01:20:27 khxpc systemd[1]: Finished systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service - Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Nov 03 01:20:27 khxpc systemd[1]: run-credentials-systemd\x2dtmpfiles\x2dclean.service.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 03 01:21:00 khxpc google-chrome.desktop[2907]: [2900:2931:1103/012100.865527:ERROR:registration_request.cc(291)] Registration response error message: DEPRECATED_ENDPOINT
Nov 03 01:22:42 khxpc kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Nov 03 01:22:55 khxpc gnome-shell[2079]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 79 with keysym 79 (keycode 1d).
Nov 03 01:22:55 khxpc gnome-shell[2079]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keysym 73 (keycode 27).
Nov 03 01:24:00 khxpc dbus-daemon[1879]: [session uid=1000 pid=1879] Activating service name='org.gnome.Settings.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=2079 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
Nov 03 01:24:00 khxpc dbus-daemon[1879]: [session uid=1000 pid=1879] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=2079 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
Nov 03 01:24:00 khxpc dbus-daemon[1879]: [session uid=1000 pid=1879] Activating service name='org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=2079 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
Nov 03 01:24:00 khxpc dbus-daemon[1879]: [session uid=1000 pid=1879] Activating service name='org.gnome.Characters' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=2079 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
Nov 03 01:24:00 khxpc dbus-daemon[1879]: [session uid=1000 pid=1879] Activating service name='org.gnome.clocks' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=2079 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
Nov 03 01:24:00 khxpc dbus-daemon[1879]: [session uid=1000 pid=1879] Activating service name='com.github.FontManager.FontManager' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=2079 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
Nov 03 01:24:00 khxpc dbus-daemon[1879]: [session uid=1000 pid=1879] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.31' (uid=1000 pid=2079 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")

Has anyone experienced similar issues or have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or fix this problem?

I updated yesterday and I am having the same problem. In addition, the kernel was corrupted, so I did clean install, but this problem persists with me as well. It sucks.

I have found temporary fix for this. When this start happening, call:
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/1/amdgpu_gpu_recover

Source: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/3647#note_2642759
